# Block "website induced" tab changes in Firefox

Tags: firefox, popups

With popular topics a lot of "free" site will give you a link to click on before getting to the actual content you want to view. They use the click to open a pop-up. I don't mind ads but those pop-ups are sometimes contain malware so I want to block them generally.

Site that rely on regular pop-ups are fairly easy to block (any simple pop-up blocker). Some times they are more persistent and won't show the content so I disable the blocker once for this single site access. But there are more and more sites that transfer the current content to a new tab (which gets blocked) and replace the content from the current tap with the pop-up content in a way that using the back button is not possible. Since the original content with the link is gone I can not just disable the pop-up blocker and try again any more.

Is there some way to block the transfer of the current content in a new window so I get a chance to disable the pop-up blocker? Or to return to the previous state somehow? I'm looking mainly for a solution for Firefox.

Comment: Can you give an example of such a website? I haven't met any like that. You could try [Popup Blocker Ultimate](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/popup-blocker-ultimate/).

Comment: I don't recall a specific one, next time I across one I will update my question. Pop-up blocker won't work in my use-case at least not the regular once that: allow/block all except black/white list.

Comment: Why bother going to that type of website.

Comment: @Moab To get the information that's on that site. I don't want to go through the trouble of finding the info on a different site, if the only thing I have to do is to disable the pop-up blocker.

Comment: Get a better ad-blocker. I haven't been plagued by those thing in ages. I use AdGuard (freeware) [but on Mac here]